# MongoDB document as a JsonNode (Jackson library)

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I have the following use case -

1. Store a JSON schema (dynamic, changes over time) in mongodb.
2. Read JSON objects from a file and validate them against the schema
   (in #1)
3. I am using this [JSON Validator](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator).
4. I need to read the schema from mongo db and convert it to JsonNode
   (Jackson library).

I am using Java..

Can anyone let me know how to convert a mongodb document to JsonNode.. I need this because the validator I am using (mentioned in #3 above) needs a JsonNode to construct the schema object.

EDIT: Is it fine performance wise to convert DBObject to JSON string and then convert it to JsonNode?

Answer (score 3):

Why not go straight from DBObject to JsonNode?  iirc, JsonNode is just a map like DBObject is.  Converting from one to the other (and back) should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ObjectReader class (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader(JsonNode.class);
JsonNode node = reader.readValue(document.toJson());
```

Here you can find some performance best practices for Jackson: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonBestPracticesPerformance