# How to directly convert MongoDB Document do Jackson JsonNode in Java

Tags: json, mongodb, jackson, type-conversion, bson

I would like to store a MongoDB Document (org.bson.Document) as a Jackson JsonNode file type. There is a outdated answer to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380264/mongodb-document-as-a-jsonnode-jackson-library), inspired by this I was able to succesfully parse the Document with

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
...
JonNode jsonData = mapper.readTree(someBsonDocument.toJson());
```

In my understanding this will:

1. Convert the Document to string
2. Parse the string and create a JsonNode object

I noticed there is some support for MongoDB/BSON for the [Jackson Project](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) - [jackson-datatype-mongo](https://github.com/commercehub-oss/jackson-datatype-mongo) and [BSON for Jackson](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/bson4jackson), but I can not figure out how to use them to do the conversion more efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure-out some solution using bson4jackson:

```
public static InputStream documentToInputStream(final Document document) {
    BasicOutputBuffer outputBuffer = new BasicOutputBuffer();
    BsonBinaryWriter writer = new BsonBinaryWriter(outputBuffer);
    new DocumentCodec().encode(writer, document, EncoderContext.builder().isEncodingCollectibleDocument(true).build());
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputBuffer.toByteArray());
}

public static JsonNode documentToJsonNode(final Document document) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new BsonFactory());
    InputStream is = documentToInputStream(document);
    return mapper.readTree(is);
}
```

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way, I am assuming it is still better solution than converting BSOn to String and parsing that string. There is an [open Ticket in the mongoDB JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1975)  for adding conversion from *Document, DBObject* and *BsonDocument* to *toBson* and vice versa, which would simplify the whole process a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate this isn't what the OP asked for - but might be helpful to some. I've managed to do this in reverse using [MongoJack](https://github.com/mongojack/mongojack). The key thing is to use the `JacksonEncoder` which can turn any Json-like object into a Bson object. Then use BsonDocumentWriter to write it to a BsonDocument instance.

```java
    @Test
    public void writeBsonDocument() throws IOException {
        JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree("{\"wibble\": \"wobble\"}");

        BsonDocument document = new BsonDocument();
        BsonDocumentWriter writer = new BsonDocumentWriter(document);

        JacksonEncoder transcoder =
                new JacksonEncoder(JsonNode.class, null, new ObjectMapper(), UuidRepresentation.UNSPECIFIED);

        var context = EncoderContext.builder().isEncodingCollectibleDocument(true).build();

        transcoder.encode(writer,jsonNode,context);
        Assertions.assertThat(document.toJson()).isEqualTo("{\"wibble\": \"wobble\"}");
    }
```