# Write BsonDocument to file in Java

Tags: java, file, bson

Is it possible to somehow write a BsonDocument object into file like BSON (not in JSON format)? I am using Java with MongoDB Java Driver for writing BsonDocuments.

I am trying somthing like this:

```
BsonDocument bson = BsonDocument.parse(someJSONString);
bson.writeBSONtoFile("someFilepath"); //this method
```

I know that this method will not work, but I am looking for something like this.

Comment: Have you seen: [How could I write a BsonDocument object into a file, and read it again, using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689874/how-could-i-write-a-bsondocument-object-into-a-file-and-read-it-again-using-ja)

Comment: Yes but this is exactly i don't want to do. This is saving bson like json

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found the workaround.
The json string convert to bsonDocument and then with DocumentCodec get byte array which it is written into file.

```
BsonDocument bson = BsonDocument.parse(someJSONString);

BasicOutputBuffer outputBuffer = new BasicOutputBuffer();
BsonBinaryWriter writer = new BsonBinaryWriter(outputBuffer);
new BsonDocumentCodec().encode(writer, bson, EncoderContext.builder().isEncodingCollectibleDocument(true).build());
byte[] byteArr = outputBuffer.toByteArray();
writeToFile(byteArr);
```

Many thanks to this guy/post
[How to directly convert MongoDB Document do Jackson JsonNode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529087/how-to-directly-convert-mongodb-document-do-jackson-jsonnode-in-java)